# JAVA returns "Linux-all-ports" as os.name. What is the significance compared to "Linux" as os.name?

Tags: java, linux, operating-system

I have two identical* systems.  One returns `"Linux-all-ports"` and one returns `"Linux"` from `System.getProperty("os.name")`.

What does `"Linux-all-ports"` mean?  And why would one system return one, and one system return the other?  Is there an internal state in JAVA that could change this property or something?

**NOTE:** The specific hardware *may not* be identical (motherboard, chipset, PCI cards, etc.) but we don't expect this to change the os.name right?  If hardware would affect os.name property, that would be great to know for sure.

*Both machines PXE boot from the same OS image (Ubuntu), and we confirmed that JAVA ver/build is identical, output of `uname` is identical, so we are quite confident the environment is identical.

Comment: I don't have an answer myself yet but it looks like this is related to the RXTX library.  Apparently the library requires that you change the os.name to control port scanning behavior.  So code using this library is what changed the name, but this is not a full explanation of why RXTX requires this.  BTW, changing the os.name breaks other JAVA libraries, so the RXTX developers are really causing us headaches, thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux system, `System.getProperty("os.name")` should return `"Linux"`.

*BUT*, the `os.name` property is not read only, so anyone can change it to an arbitrary value.  (This seems crazy).

`"Linux-all-ports"` has no significance outside of the RXTX library; it was made up by the developers of that project.  Someone set the `os.name` to that value to trigger some magic switch in the RXTX library, and never set it back.

tl;dr section:

Setting system properties can be useful when starting the JVM, if your application needs some custom settings.  But making them writable from the application seems awkward.

I had assumed something like `os.name` would never be a user-settable value so I assumed that what it was set to was significant.  But this is not the case.  You could change the `os.name` from `"Linux"` to `"ZippityFreakinDooDaa"` and completely break everything.

Oracle [acknowledges this here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html):

```
Warning: Changing system properties is potentially dangerous and should be done with discretion. Many system properties are not reread after start-up and are there for informational purposes. Changing some properties may have unexpected side-effects.
```

Apparently the system properties can be protected (made read-only) with the [Security Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html).